# How to find the script for demo in a package to read?

Tags: r

I installed the package `bayess`, and ran a demo as follows:

```
library(bayess)
demo(Chapter.1)
```

I wonder how to find the script for the demo to be read in, for example, R terminal, or preferably, emacs, gedit, ...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `system.file(package='bayess')`.

That should give you folder path to where the `bayess` library is saved in your system. Within that folder you should see `demo` folder which should contain all the demo scripts.